# How to retrieve the size and clear a sesame repository using Java API

Tags: sparql, sesame

Some functions of the openrdf-workbench for sesame 2.7 are really usefull.

- obtain repository's size
- clear the repository

How can someone do that using java API ?

for the reposirory size, is it necessary to use a sparql query

```
SELECT ?x ?y ?z WHERE { ?x ?y ?z }
```

and then count the resultSet. ?

and for clearing the repository, do SPARQ has clauses to delete triples ?

thanks

Comment: Duplicate of http://answers.semanticweb.com/questions/25627/how-to-reset-and-get-size-of-a-sesame-repository-from-java-api

Comment: As Jeen notes this is duplicated elsewhere with an accepted answer - http://answers.semanticweb.com/questions/25627/how-to-reset-and-get-size-of-a-sesame-repository-from-java-api/25628